# How to replace ONCLICK to an automated action performed in interval of time

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick

Here is my code

```
<a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_single" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.1_new_update'}</a>
```

I want the action of Onclik to be performed automatically in an interval of 10 seconds without clicking anything

I want to replace ONCLICK by setInterval but I don't know how to do it for it to work properly.
The Code is from an Activity Feed that needs a click to upload new feed updates, what I want is the feed update to load automatically without click. I want any there is a new activity I want to upload automatically on the page

Comment: You have already asked the same question? Even this time also you haven't tag any language. Is it javascript?

Comment: window.setTimeout($Core.loadMoreFeeds, 1000); 10 seconds is a little excessive

Comment: Doesn't work I still didn't the solution to integrate with following code for it to work correctly --------------------- <a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_single" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.1_new_update'}</a> <a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_plural" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.span_id_js_new_update_view_span_new_updates'}</a> ---------------------------------------- I no want to click any button, i want to do the action automaticaly in each 10s

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("activity_feed_updates_link_single").click()
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Please how to insert this code setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("activity_feed_updates_link_single").click()
}, 10000);

to this

<a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_single" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.1_new_update'}</a>

Comment: like this: `<script>setInterval(function() {
document.getElementById("activity_feed_updates_link_single").click()
}, 10000);</script>` 
I didn't understand first that you want to drop the onclick attribute. For that, see Philip's comment to your question and change setTimeout to setInterval in it.

Comment: Doesn't work
I still didn't the solution to integrate with following code for it to work correctly
---------------------
<a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_single" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.1_new_update'}</a>
  <a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_plural" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.span_id_js_new_update_view_span_new_updates'}</a>
----------------------------------------
I no want to click any button, i want to do the action automaticaly in each 10s

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

It registers an event listener which will fire after the document content is loaded.

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript">window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    function(event) { setInterval(function() {
        alert('time flies when you\'re having fun');
    }, 1e4);
}, false);</script></head><body></body></html>
```

Save this code as HTML document, e.g. interval.html, and open it in your browser.

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

MDN is a great resource of definitive information!

Might want to add MDN as a search engine:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=setInterval

Comment: An if I want the action to be repeated periodically in the interval on 10 second ?

Comment: Doesn't work I still didn't the solution to integrate with following code for it to work correctly --------------------- <a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_single" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.1_new_update'}</a> <a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_plural" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.span_id_js_new_update_view_span_new_updates'}</a> ---------------------------------------- I no want to click any button, i want to do the action automaticaly in each 10s

Comment: Your comment above is not readable. Please make it short and clear.

Comment: This is the code I want to modify, I want to replace the onclick event to an setInterval for it to be perfomed automaticaly without any click. I want to know how to insert the setInterval code in it.
'<a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_single" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.1_new_update'}</a> <a <a href="#" id="activity_feed_updates_link_plural" class="activity_feed_updates_link" onclick="return $Core.loadMoreFeeds();">{phrase var='feed.span_id_js_new_update_view_span_new_updates'}</a>'